# SharePoint 2013 How to disable streaming video from downloading

Tags: document-library, video, sharepont

In SharePoint 2013 how to disable streaming video from downloading across browsers (IE, CHROME. FIREFOX etc.).

Video uploaded on SharePoint, User can only view video, they should not allowed to download or copy in to local machine.

Comment: There is already similar question here: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/29984/using-information-management-policies-to-prevent-users-from-downloading-videos-f

Answer (score 0):

OOTB SharePoint 2013 do not provide a real streaming service. However [it support live streaming video](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/112501/sharepoint-2013-video-live-streaming) provided by an external streaming server or service (like youtube)

So the video you uploaded to SharePoint are not providing to user thru "streaming". They are actually "downloading" to their local cache and play. If you want to provide real streaming you need to purchase 3rd party engine or build your own.